# how to import mongo variable from the app which is binded to app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

i have a files like app.py and views.py

## app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["MONGO_URI"] = "mongodb://local:27017/local"
mongo = PyMongo(app)
from views import profileview
profileview.register(app, route_prefix='/profile/')

if __name__== "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

## views.py

```
from flask_classy import FlaskView , route
# i am unable to import the app in views
from app import mongo

class profileview(FlaskView):
    route_base = '/'
    
    @route("/user/",methods=["GET"])
    def index(self):
        pass
```

when i run the server it showing that cannot
import from views import profileview, how to avoid the circular import

Answer (score 0):

this is how to avoid circular import :

**db.py**

```
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
mongo = PyMongo()
```

**app.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from db import mongo

    mongo.init_app(app)
```

**views.py**

`from db import mongo`

or you could use the factory pattern and make a create_app function.